# How to get back the UIButton border in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, xcode5

I built an old project in [iOS SDK 6.1 in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5). However, the UIbutton is borderless when the app runs on an iPhone running iOS 7.  I have checked the `.xib` is "Builds for" > "Project Deployment Target (5.0)":

[image]

How can I config Xcode 5 to build the project to show an iOS 6.1-style UIButton?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295703/ios-7-and-button-and-border

Comment: @AbdullahMd.Zubair it's not a duplicate. I am compiling an iOS SDK 6.1 app, not an iOS SDK 7 app.

Comment: use `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` frame work and set layerBorder = 1 ;..

Comment: @ohho when your app run on ios7, it gets compiled on ios7

Comment: Check out this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295703/ios-7-and-button-and-border/28259540#28259540

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can create a category:

```
- (void)setRoundedBorder:(float) radius borderWidth:(float)borderWidth color:(UIColor*)color
{
    CALayer * l = [self layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:radius];
    // You can even add a border
    [l setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
    [l setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];
}
```

Comment: I prefer to set the background images using resizable images. Checkout variations of the [UIButton for iOS 7 and touch behavior](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/1/22/programmatic-uibutton-on-ios-70-create-a-uibutton-with-code).

Answer (score 10):

Try this

set border width of button by using `QuartzCore` Framework

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

button.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to introduce any of the iOS 7 changes changing the SDK is not enough. You shouldn't leave the Interface Builder "Opens in" property unchanged as well.

I leave mine in "Xcode 4.6" and everything looks as it should.

I think the only advantage you would take is with the new auto-layout.